# Command binding in code behind

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding, command

I am trying to bind a command in code behind of a custom control.  The control itself doesn't have a ViewModel but the page which it is going to be a part of has one. That view model has multiple commands defined like New,Save,Delete against button clicks. Since now i have to create those buttons programmatically i also have to bind their commands in code which were previously happening via XAML binding.

Please note that i could have bound the commands in code as following if they were defined in the codebehind of control by using following approach.

```
Click.SetCommand(newButton, commandNew);
```

But since they are present in the Viewmodel of its containing page i can't figure out the way to do it.
I have employed the following approach without much success. Although it works for binding of other properties defined in same View Model!

```
  RadButton newButton =  new RadButton(); // create a new rad button
  Binding commandBinding = new Binding(); //create a command 
  commandBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("commandNew");
  Click.SetCommand(newButton , commandBinding as ICommand);
  buttonToolbar.Items.Add(newButton );
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been sorted. In the above code where I am dynamically binding the command I should have been using following line of code.

```
newButton.SetBinding(RadButton.CommandProperty, commandBinding);
```